# How to set the algorithm to barrier when use CPLEX in PuLP

Tags: python, cplex, pulp

I use 'prob.solve(CPLEX())' to call CPLEX in PuLP.

However, I am wondering how to use barrier algorithm here to get a more non-zero solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PuLP expert, but it looks like this is possible (however, I'm not sure how reliable it is).  There is a [hint](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pulp-or-discuss/gx1KTAH2SAE) here about how you can set CPLEX parameters using the CPLEX DLL shared library.  I believe this is outdated, but here is the corresponding snippet from that thread:

```
>>>> solver = CPLEX_DLL()
>>>> CplexDll.CPXsetintparam(solver.env, CPX_PARAM_MIPDISPLAY, 4)
Good point I would prefer
 >>> solver.CPXsetintparam(CPX_PARAM_MIPDISPLAY, 4)
As this only requires Knowledge of CPLEX parameters and not Pulp internals
```

However, with a recent version of PuLP (version 1.6.1), it looks like the `CPLEX_DLL` class has the `setLpAlgorithm` method to make this more convenient.  Here is an example, just to give you the gist:

```
>>> from pulp import *
>>> cplex_dll_path
'<path_on_your_machine>/libcplex1263.so'
>>> solver = CPLEX()
>>> solver.setLpAlgorithm(4)
```

`<path_on_your_machine>/libcplex1263.so` must be configured in the `pulp.cfg.(linux|osx|win)` file (in the directory where the pulp module is installed). The magic number "4" in `solver.setLpAlgorithm(4)` corresponds to `CPX_ALG_BARRIER` (see [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/LPMETHOD.html)).

With that said, if you want finer control over CPLEX, you might have better luck using the [CPLEX Python API](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/help.html?pos=2) directly (although, it is a lower-level API than PuLP).  Alternatively, check out the higher-level [docplex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docplex) package which also allows you to solve on the cloud.